# Mapping runtime types to a parallel class hierarchy … with templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-erasure, virtual-functions

I have two class hierarchies which have a 1:1 relationship: some normal classes `A`, `B` which have a common `Root` interface, and a `WrapperRoot<T>` interface with two concrete instantiations `WrapperA<T>` and `WrapperB<T>`. I am now looking to implement a function `auto wrap<T>(Root& elem) -> unique_ptr<WrapperRoot<T>>` that maps each normal class to its wrapper class.

[image: UML class diagram of the described hierarchy]

The exact type of the wrappers is important as they will have virtual methods, and the exact type of the `Root` objects is not statically known.

### Attempted solutions

My first idea was to declare a template virtual method in `Root`:

```
class Root {
  ...
public:
  template<typename T>
  virtual auto wrap() -> unique_ptr<WrapperRoot<T>> = 0;
}
```

which could then be implemented in the child classes as

```
class A : public Root {
  ...
  template<typename T>
  virtual auto wrap() -> unique_ptr<WrapperRoot<T>> override {
    return make_unique<WrapperA<T>>();
  }
}
```

As I was to find out, C++ does not allow templates for virtual methods. I did some further research and found the technique of *type erasure*, which allows us to break through this virtual vs. template dichtomy. Perhaps it might be possible to have each class select their wrapper type by passing in a visitor-like object that has erased the template parameter `<T>`? However, I am still fairly new to C++, and all my attempts to implement this have only moved the problem into another level, but not solved them.

This is especially frustrating since other languages which I am familiar with have no problem expressing this structure. E.g. in Java it is no problem to define a virtual method `<T> WrapperRoot<T> wrap() { return new WrapperA<T>(); }`, but that is because Java implements templates via reinterpreting casts. Java's implementation would be phrased in C++ as:

```
template<typename T>
WrapperRoot<T>* wrap() { return reinterpret_cast<WrapperRoot<T>*>(wrapper_impl()); }
virtual void* wrapper_impl() { return new WrapperA<void*>() }
```

However, I would like to work *with* the C++ type system rather than violating it by casting void pointers around.

### Test Case

To phrase my problem unambiguously, I have created the below test case. Once `wrap` is implemented correctly, it should output this:

```
WrapperA
WrapperB
```

The `main` method should not be modified, but arbitrary methods, helper types, and an implementation for the `wrap` function may be added.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

// the Root hierarchy

class Root {
public:
  virtual ~Root() {}
};

class A : public Root {};

class B : public Root {};


// the Wrapper hierarchy

template<typename T>
class WrapperRoot {
public:
  virtual ~WrapperRoot() {}
  virtual T name() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class WrapperA : public WrapperRoot<T> {
public:
  virtual T name() { return T("WrapperA\n"); }
};

template<typename T>
class WrapperB : public WrapperRoot<T> {
public:
  virtual T name() { return T("WrapperB\n"); }
};


// the "wrap" function I want to implement

template<typename T>
auto wrap(Root& ) -> unique_ptr<WrapperRoot<T>>;

// util
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_unique(Args... args) -> unique_ptr<T> {
  return unique_ptr<T>(new T(forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main() {
  unique_ptr<Root> a = make_unique<A>();
  unique_ptr<Root> b = make_unique<B>();
  cout << wrap<string>(*a)->name()
       << wrap<string>(*b)->name();
}
```

How can I make this work? Or do I need to resort to type-violating hacks?

Comment: I don't quite understand the relation between `WrapperRoot` and `Root`. In your test case, there seems to be none. I'm especially interested in what role the template parameter plays within that relation. Shall there be a `WrapperRoot` interface that is independent from `T`?

Comment: ^ That. It you want it to work, you at least have to specify a link between `A` and `WrapperA` (for example) at some point.

Comment: @dyp The relation between `WrapperRoot` and `Root` is in the static type of the `wrap` function, which is responsible for connecting each class with the corresponding `Wrapper*`. How I can safely specify this connection is the problem I'm struggling with. The `WrapperRoot<T>` template is a crucial part of the problem, else I could simply used virtual methods. In the test case, the necessity of the template is enforced through the `virtual T name()` method declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get this to work would just be `dynamic_cast`ing the `Root&` to work out what the runtime type of it is:

```
template<typename T>
auto wrap(Root& root) -> unique_ptr<WrapperRoot<T>>
{
    if (dynamic_cast<A*>(&root)) {
        //root is an A, return a WrapperA
        return make_unique<WrapperA<T>>();
    } 
    else if (dynamic_cast<B*>(&root)) {
        //root is a B, return a WrapperB
        return make_unique<WrapperB<T>>();
    } 

    throw std::runtime_error("No wrapper for that type");
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4920cf47ab60f12)

Comment: Hmm, this is about as elegant as a drunken hippo at 3am, but it certainly beats casting void pointers and is conveniently self-contained. I'll see if I can make this work.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this can be solved with type erasure, the Visitor Pattern, and a bit of indirection. The solution is clean, and does not require us to re-implement dynamic dispatch inside the `wrap` function.

The core idea is to introduce a `WrapperSelector` visitor interface:

```
class WrapperSelector {
public:
  virtual auto visit(A&) -> void = 0;
  virtual auto visit(B&) -> void = 0;
};
```

The `Root` hierarchy needs to be modified a bit to accept this visitor, and to perform the double dispatch:

```
class Root {
public:
  virtual ~Root() {}
  virtual auto accept(WrapperSelector&) -> void = 0;
};

class A : public Root {
public:
  virtual auto accept(WrapperSelector& wrapper) -> void {
    wrapper.visit(*this);
  }
};

class B : public Root {
public:
  virtual auto accept(WrapperSelector& wrapper) -> void {
    wrapper.visit(*this);
  }
};
```

So far, this is the bog-standard Visitor Pattern in C++. What we now do is introduce a templated class `WrapperSelectorImpl<T> : public WrapperSelector`. Since it is templated but only used through the un-templated interface, this implements type erasure. Internally, we construct this `WrapperSelectorImpl` as a container for a borrowed `WrapperRoot<T>` pointer, into which we write the selected wrapper. After the `accept`/`visit` sequence has ended, that pointer will be filled with the wrapper, so no virtual method needs to return a template-parameterized type. Also, the `accept` method does nothing but select the corresponding `visit` method, so the types in the `Root` hierarchy don't need to know about the `WrapperRoot` hierarchy – a concrete `WrapperSelector` will handle this mapping.

```
template<typename T>
class WrapperSelectorImpl : public WrapperSelector {
  unique_ptr<WrapperRoot<T>>& _wrapper;
public:
  explicit WrapperSelectorImpl(unique_ptr<WrapperRoot<T>>& wrapper)
    : _wrapper(wrapper)
  {}

  virtual auto visit(A&) -> void override {
    _wrapper = make_unique<WrapperA<T>>();
  }

  virtual auto visit(B&) -> void override {
    _wrapper = make_unique<WrapperB<T>>();
  }
};
```

Our `wrap` function must now set up a pointer, a `WrapperSelectorImpl` which borrows that pointer, let the given object in the `Root` hierarchy select the wrapper through the `WrapperSelector`, and return the now-populated pointer:

```
template<typename T>
auto wrap(Root& obj) -> unique_ptr<WrapperRoot<T>> {
  unique_ptr<WrapperRoot<T>> wrapper;
  WrapperSelectorImpl<T> wrapper_selector(wrapper);
  obj.accept(wrapper_selector);
  return wrapper;
}
```

### Generalization

The above technique can be used to implement arbitrary templated virtual methods, or the visitor pattern with arbitrary return types. The prerequisites for this is minimal support for the Visitor Pattern`:

- some `Subject` class or class hierarchy with a `virtual void accept(SubjectVisitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }`.
- some `SubjectVisitor` interface with `virtual void visit(S&) = 0` methods for each class `S` in the `Subject` class hierarchy.

Now assume we wish to implement a method with the following pseudo-signature in the `Subject` hierarchy:

```
class Subject {
  ...
  template<typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
  virtual R frobnicate(Args... args) = 0;
}
```

We can then use the following steps to implement this:

First, we create a wrapper function that exposes the public interface of our dispatching logic. This might be a non-virtual templated method in `Subject`, or a free function. The internals are the same as in the above example: Set-up of the return value, set-up of the visitor (borrowing a reference to the return value), doing the dispatch, and returning the value.

Since this is so general, we can pack this into a reusable templated function:

```
// most general implementation
template<typename ReturnType, typename Subject, typename Visitor, typename... Args>
auto manage_visitor(Subject& subject, Args... args) -> ReturnType {
  ReturnType return_value;
  Visitor visitor(return_value, std::forward(args)...);
  subject.accept(visitor);
  return return_value;
}

class Subject {
  ...
  template<typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
  R frobnicate(Args... args) {
    return manage_visitor<R, Subject, ConcreteSubjectVisitor<R, T>>(*this, std::forward(args)...);
  }
};
```

Note that this assumes the return value to be default-constructible. If this is not the case, substituting `unique_ptr<ReturnType>` for `ReturnType` could be a solution.

We now have to provide a `class ConcreteSubjectVisitor : public SubjectVisitor` that provides the actual implementation.

```
template<typename ReturnType, typename T>
class ConcreteSubjectVisitor : public SubjectVisitor {
  ReturnType& return_value;
  ArgType something;
public:
  ConcreteSubjectVisitor(ReturnType& ret, ArgType& other_arg) : return_value(ret), something(other_arg) {}
  virtual void visit(S1&) override { ... }
  virtual void visit(S2&) override { ... }
  ...
};
```

The only thing which matters is that it can write to the return value. Note that the visitor can take additional arguments through the constructor, which makes it somewhat related to the `std::bind` function or to constructing a lambda. The `visit` definitions then contain the actual code, which has access to all type parameters of the visitor, and all constructor arguments of the visitor.

Open problems:

- handling of return types that are not default-constructible (pointers or custom defaults)
- specialization for `void` return type (problem decays to “normal” visitor pattern)
- generalization to full multi-methods (trivial if method is in curried form)
- providing a convenient interface
- const-correctness (must be applied on a per-visitor basis, `Subject::accept` can be provided as const and non-const).